# Tensorflow Addon's Cohen Kappa Return 0 for all epochs

Tags: tensorflow, metrics, kappa

I was having an issue with tensorflow_addons's CohenKappa metric. I'm trying to train an image classification model, but I frame this problem as a regression problem. So, I trained the model with MSE loss. However, I need to know the classification performance and I want to use CohenKappa. Gladly, Tensorflow supports CohenKappa metric using an addon called tensorflow_addons. But, I need to customize the metric, so I add an additional logic to clip the y_pred, round them, then feed them to the CohenKappa API. Here's the code:

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow_addons.metrics import CohenKappa
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Metric
from tensorflow_addons.utils.types import AcceptableDTypes, FloatTensorLike

from typeguard import typechecked
from typing import Optional

from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import losses_utils
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import metrics_utils

class CohenKappaMetric(CohenKappa):
    def __init__(
        self,
        num_classes: FloatTensorLike,
        name: str = "cohen_kappa",
        weightage: Optional[str] = None,
        sparse_labels: bool = False,
        regression: bool = False,
        dtype: AcceptableDTypes = None,
      ):
      """Creates a `CohenKappa` instance."""
      super().__init__(num_classes=num_classes, name=name, weightage=weightage, sparse_labels=sparse_labels,
                        regression=regression,dtype=dtype)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, 0, 4)
        y_pred = tf.math.round(y_pred)
        y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, dtype=tf.uint8)

        y_true = math_ops.cast(y_true, self._dtype)
        y_pred = math_ops.cast(y_pred, self._dtype)
        [y_true, y_pred], sample_weight = \
            metrics_utils.ragged_assert_compatible_and_get_flat_values([y_true, y_pred], sample_weight)
        print(f'y_true after ragged assert: {y_true}')
        print(f'y_pred after ragged assert: {y_pred}')
        y_pred, y_true = losses_utils.squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(y_pred, y_true)
        print(f'y_true after squeeze: {y_true}')
        print(f'y_pred after squeeze: {y_pred}')
             
        return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
```

I trained it using tf's Keras API and using tf.Dataset object. Here's the full script for context. 
**========= Full script ==========**

```
# Import Library

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import cv2
from PIL import Image

import tensorflow as tf
from keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import applications 
from keras.callbacks import Callback, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import models

import os, glob, pathlib

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score, accuracy_score, confusion_matrix

from tqdm import tqdm

SIZE = 224
DATASET_DIR = 'Dataset/APTOS-2019-RAW/'
BATCH_SIZE = 32
RESHUFFLE = 700
model_backbone = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0
ARCH = 'EfficientNetB0'

train_df = pd.read_csv('Dataset/CSVs/converted_x_train_8.csv')
valid_df = pd.read_csv('Dataset/CSVs/converted_x_valid_8.csv')

#resample
from sklearn.utils import resample
X=train_df
normal=X[X.diagnosis==0]
mild=X[X.diagnosis==1]
moderate=X[X.diagnosis==2]
severe=X[X.diagnosis==3]
pdr=X[X.diagnosis==4]

#downsampled
mild = resample(mild,
                replace=True, # sample with replacement
                n_samples=RESHUFFLE, # match number in majority class
                random_state=2020) # reproducible results
moderate = resample(moderate,
                    replace=False, # sample with replacement
                    n_samples=RESHUFFLE, # match number in majority class
                    random_state=2020) # reproducible results
severe = resample(severe,
                  replace=True, # sample with replacement
                  n_samples=RESHUFFLE, # match number in majority class
                  random_state=2020) # reproducible results
normal = resample(normal,
                  replace=False, # sample with replacement
                  n_samples=RESHUFFLE, # match number in majority class
                  random_state=2020) # reproducible results
pdr = resample(pdr,
               replace=True, # sample with replacement
               n_samples=RESHUFFLE, # match number in majority class
               random_state=2020) # reproducible results    

# combine minority and downsampled majority
sampled = pd.concat([normal, mild, moderate, severe, pdr])

# checking counts
sampled.diagnosis.value_counts()

train_df = sampled
train_df = train_df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

train_df['id_code'] = train_df['id_code'].apply(lambda x: DATASET_DIR+x)
valid_df['id_code'] = valid_df['id_code'].apply(lambda x: DATASET_DIR+x)

list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(list(train_df['id_code']), shuffle=False)
list_ds = list_ds.shuffle(len(train_df), reshuffle_each_iteration=True)

val_list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(list(valid_df['id_code']), shuffle=False)
val_list_ds = val_list_ds.shuffle(len(valid_df), reshuffle_each_iteration=True)

class_names = np.array(sorted([item.name for item in pathlib.Path(DATASET_DIR).glob('*') if item.name != "LICENSE.txt"]))
print(class_names)

train_ds = list_ds
val_ds = val_list_ds

def get_label(file_path):
  # convert the path to a list of path components
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  # The second to last is the class-directory
  one_hot = parts[-2] == class_names
  # Integer encode the label
  return tf.argmax(one_hot)

def decode_img(img):
  # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  # resize the image to the desired size
  return tf.image.resize(img, [SIZE, SIZE])

def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  # load the raw data from the file as a string
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

# Set `num_parallel_calls` so multiple images are loaded/processed in parallel.
train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

def configure_for_performance(ds):
  ds = ds.cache()
  ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
  ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
  ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
  return ds

train_ds = configure_for_performance(train_ds)
val_ds = configure_for_performance(val_ds)

import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow_addons.metrics import CohenKappa
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Metric
from tensorflow_addons.utils.types import AcceptableDTypes, FloatTensorLike

from typeguard import typechecked
from typing import Optional

from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import losses_utils
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import metrics_utils

class CohenKappaMetric(CohenKappa):
    def __init__(
        self,
        num_classes: FloatTensorLike,
        name: str = "cohen_kappa",
        weightage: Optional[str] = None,
        sparse_labels: bool = False,
        regression: bool = False,
        dtype: AcceptableDTypes = None,
      ):
      """Creates a `CohenKappa` instance."""
      super().__init__(num_classes=num_classes, name=name, weightage=weightage, sparse_labels=sparse_labels,
                        regression=regression,dtype=dtype)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, 0, 4)
        y_pred = tf.math.round(y_pred)
        y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, dtype=tf.uint8)

        y_true = math_ops.cast(y_true, self._dtype)
        y_pred = math_ops.cast(y_pred, self._dtype)
        [y_true, y_pred], sample_weight = \
            metrics_utils.ragged_assert_compatible_and_get_flat_values([y_true, y_pred], sample_weight)
        print(f'y_true after ragged assert: {y_true}')
        print(f'y_pred after ragged assert: {y_pred}')
        y_pred, y_true = losses_utils.squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(y_pred, y_true)
        print(f'y_true after squeeze: {y_true}')
        print(f'y_pred after squeeze: {y_pred}')
             
        return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)

class QWKCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, patience = 10):
      super().__init__()
      self.patience = patience

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        # The number of epoch it has waited when loss is no longer minimum.
        self.wait = 0
        # The epoch the training stops at.
        self.stopped_epoch = 0
        # Initialize the best as infinity.
        self.best = -1

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current = logs.get("cohen_kappa")
        if np.greater(current, self.best):
            self.best = current
            self.wait = 0
            # Record the best weights if current results is better (less).
            self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
            if current > 0.75:
              print("Validation Kappa has improved and greater than 0.75. Worth saving, dude. Saving model.")
              self.model.save(f'Kaggle - Model Weights/{ARCH}-model.h5')
        else:
            self.wait += 1
            if self.wait >= self.patience:
                self.stopped_epoch = epoch
                self.model.stop_training = True
                print("Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.")
                self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)

    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        if self.stopped_epoch > 0:
            print("Epoch %05d: early stopping" % (self.stopped_epoch + 1))

efficientnet = model_backbone(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(SIZE,SIZE,3))

dummy_model = Sequential([
    Rescaling(1/.255, input_shape = (224, 224, 3)),
    RandomFlip(seed = 2019),
    RandomRotation((-0.5, 0.5), fill_mode = 'constant', seed = 2019),
    RandomZoom(0.1),
    layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    layers.Dense(10), 
    layers.Dense(1)])

dummy_model.compile(
    loss='mse',
    optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001),
    metrics = [CohenKappaMetric(num_classes=5, weightage='quadratic', sparse_labels = True)]
)

dummy_model.fit(
    train_ds,
    epochs = 9,
    validation_data = val_ds,
    callbacks = [QWKCallback(patience = 10)]
)
```

The result of this script is this log:

```
Epoch 1/9
y_true after ragged assert: Tensor("Cast_2:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
y_pred after ragged assert: Tensor("Cast_3:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
y_true after squeeze: Tensor("Cast_2:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
y_pred after squeeze: Tensor("Cast_3:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
y_true after ragged assert: Tensor("Cast_2:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
y_pred after ragged assert: Tensor("Cast_3:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
y_true after squeeze: Tensor("Cast_2:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
y_pred after squeeze: Tensor("Cast_3:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
109/110 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 144816.2047 - cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00y_true after ragged assert: Tensor("Cast_2:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
y_pred after ragged assert: Tensor("Cast_3:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
y_true after squeeze: Tensor("Cast_2:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
y_pred after squeeze: Tensor("Cast_3:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
110/110 [==============================] - 3s 18ms/step - loss: 144618.4215 - cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 119745.2266 - val_cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/9
110/110 [==============================] - 2s 16ms/step - loss: 105063.3554 - cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 86080.0625 - val_cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/9
110/110 [==============================] - 2s 16ms/step - loss: 75889.1368 - cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 60222.9531 - val_cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/9
110/110 [==============================] - 2s 16ms/step - loss: 52277.5727 - cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 40955.3906 - val_cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/9
110/110 [==============================] - 2s 16ms/step - loss: 35806.8430 - cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 26828.6133 - val_cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/9
110/110 [==============================] - 2s 16ms/step - loss: 23043.7091 - cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 16888.7090 - val_cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/9
110/110 [==============================] - 2s 16ms/step - loss: 14327.0133 - cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 10193.4795 - val_cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/9
110/110 [==============================] - 2s 16ms/step - loss: 8697.9348 - cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 5862.7231 - val_cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/9
110/110 [==============================] - 2s 16ms/step - loss: 4940.2150 - cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 3193.6562 - val_cohen_kappa: 0.0000e+00
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f6c285d6c50>
```

From these results, I have two questions:

- How to fix this so I can get a working cohen kappa metric? It should improve from 0 to 1.
- I want to see y_pred and y_true for each metric update_state method, is it expected to have Tensor object as y_true and y_pred? Thanks!

Comment: Share your public notebook if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, after several moments I discovered where I was wrong. tensorflow addons isn't supporting tf.data yet, so the quick fix for this is stated on this github issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/2417